# I can't create component, page, or dialog with CRXDE

Tags: sdk, editor, adobe, aem

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/developing/devtools/developing-with-crxde-lite.html?lang=en#creating-a-template) about how to create a new template from CRXDE, but I can't see the mentioned option "Create template" in the contextual menu in my author instance for aem. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtEzd.png), I have only three options, but none of them is what I need.

Has anyone had the same problem?

AEM SDK for AEM v2021.6.5586.20210628T210726Z-210600

Thanks!

Comment: That option is to create static templates, for the AEM version (cloud) that you are using I suspect that they are deprecated. I am able to see the option with a local AEM but it is the standard. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/platform/templates/page-templates-static.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks Ronny, I think you're right because in the [cloud version documentation](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/developer-tools/crxde.html?lang=en#creating-a-node), the option for creating templates with contextual menu is not mentioned anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Adobe's documentation, static templates are no longer supported in latest cloud versions.